# Using mklink to sync game saves between PCs

Tags: mklink

I have three computers on a network that I want to have the same Terraria Characters on each. I'm pretty sure that `mklink` in the Command Prompt has the capability to do this. I have an NAS that I've been using as a brigde. I've played around with it but so far I have not made any progress. The best I have is:

`mklink /d "%USERPROFILE%\My Games\Terraria\Players" "\\NAS\Terraria\Players"`

But this returns 'Cannot Create a file when that file already exists.'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message states that `"%USERPROFILE%\My Games\Terraria\Players"` already exists. If it is an empty directory, remove it and run the command again.

Comment: Okay it worked, but all I see is a shortcut to a nonexistent folder. I don't think that this does what I want. What exactly is this doing?